# Why there is a delay in running a console application just created?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, console-application

I have noticed this for a while. After building a cpp console application, when i run it through command prompt, the first time it takes some time to run. The second time, third time, etc it runs instantly.
Why this delay? Can anything be done?

Comment: The OS has likely cached the application binary after the first run so it doesn't have to be loaded from disk on the second run. If you reboot your machine you'll probably see the first run after the reboot being slow again since the application has to be loaded from disk again.

Comment: Without knowing anything further about the application I'd assume the first time it is loaded from disk, which is a pretty slow operation, while later on the executable is already cached in the system's memory (RAM). If there are no other reasons that might prevent your application from starting quickly then you cannot do anything about...

Comment: It's possible the initial delay is due to anti-virus scanning. You could try whitelisting the directory you develop in.

Comment: Caching might be another reason. (again, might)

Comment: ***Can anything be done?*** Turn off your antivirus and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm Turning the AV off entirely doesn't look like a good idea to me, whitelisting is the better alternative...

Comment: It was a quick check. Whitelisting you can get wrong depending on the user interface.

Comment: It was the 'Real time protection' in antivirus. I turned it off for '30 minutes' and the delay ( in question) did not occured. I continued to edit my code and build. Later the delay occured and i found it was because 30 minutes was over and 'real time protection' was on again. This happened after next 30 minutes also. Thanks everyone for finding this out.

Answer (score 0):

Turned off the 'Real Time Protection' in my antivirus and this problem was solved.